# clion docker gcc компилятор

Tags: gcc, docker, clion

Установил clion но для компиляции нужен MinGW, но я решил пойти другим способом через docker.
Я установил плагин в clion и контейнер gcc для компиляции.

Я их связал но при компиляции выходит ошибка:

```
Deploying 'gcc  Image Id: 61eb6c42f780'...
Creating container...
Failed to deploy 'gcc  Image Id: 61eb6c42f780': com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"No such image: 61eb6c42f7804b5a9bf9698893cece48e8b1abe3905b222bffc6f53c7c642206:latest"}
```

Ошибка означает что clion не может найти контейнер?

Скриншоты моей настройки в clion
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

id и name контейнера введены верно и пути тоже.
Навастривал по  [документации jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/docker.html)

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Странно, что он обращается к изображению по айдишнику, попробуйте указать привычное человекочитаемое название

Comment: изменил image id на id начало выходить сообщение что успешно.                             
>Deploying 'gcc  Image Id: gcc'...
>Creating container...
>Container Id: e359a864d4faa526bea98f9c2a20eb01481062ac0daede7f1daf3def324a353b
>Attaching to container 'gcc'...
>Starting container 'gcc'
>'gcc  Image Id: gcc' has been deployed successfully.
но почему в консоли нет того что программа компилируется успешно и выполняется?

Comment: этой конфигурацией вы просто запускаете docker-контейнер. CLion понятия не имеет, что в нем gcc, вы просто говорите ему запустить контейнер - и он запускает. Насколько понимаю, вам надо как-то добавить экземпляр gcc (а не докер-контейнера), который по факту будет оберткой над `docker run <repo>/gcc <аргументы, поступившие из clion>`, и который будет отдавать результат прямо в stdout, других способов я не вижу. Возможно, CLion умеет запускать gcc по ssh, в этом случае вам стоит поднять постоянный контейнер с ssh-демоном и бинарником gcc внутри.